# KeyPress event in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, keypress

This was very simple in VB.NET, I would just do the following

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        e.Handled = True
        cmdOk.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

I can't figure out how to do the equivalent in C#, not for the text box or the form in general. In Form1.cs, in the top left where the drop-down menu thing is, there is no option to generate a method for events (like how you can generate a Sub in VB), all I have is WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1

Comment: In the future, please use the [tag:winforms] tag when your question is specific to Windows Forms.

Comment: Didn't know such a tag existed, thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend the Windows Standard approach as Hans points out. In addition you can use [CodeChanger](http://codechanger.com/) to convert VB.Net to C# and vice versa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the textbox first.  Ensure you are seeing the Properties window, use the View menu if you don't.  Click the lightning bolt icon and locate the KeyPress event.  Double click it.  Then make it look similar to this:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter) {
            e.Handled = true;
            cmdOk.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

This is not in fact the Right Way to do it, not in VB.NET either.  Set the form's AcceptButton property to cmdOk so you don't have to write any code.  You'll now also get a heavy border around the OK button so the user knows that this is the key that gets activated when she presses Enter.  Pick up a book about Winforms programming from your local library, these things are hard to guess at through trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Code examples can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)

To automatically create the method for specific events just use the dropdown in top of the properties-window of the control.

I've got no VS right here, but you may have a look at [this youtube-video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq9KGE6-7qk) @ 0:40 you see a VS screenshot and in the bottom right corner you will find the property-window. On its top you'll find the dropdown for events.

Answer (score 0):

select your textbox, open property window, click on Events icon nereast to properties icon you can see the list of events, double click on 'KeyPress'

Answer (score 0):

On the Form properties you can link the events to the Key's events defined by your event code.  Or link those through code based on KeyFormcode. I updated this to VS 2015 with c#:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KeyDemoForm
{
public partial class KeyDemoForm : Form
{

   public KeyDemoForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void KeyDemoForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        charLabel.Text = "Key pressed: " + e.KeyChar;
    }

    public void KeyDemoForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyInfoLabel.Text =
         "Alt:  " + (e.Alt ? "yes" : "No") + '\n' +
         "Shift:  " + (e.Shift ? "yes" : "No") + '\n' +
         "Ctrl:  " + (e.Control ? "yes" : "No") + '\n' +
         "KeyCode:  " + e.KeyCode + '\n' +
         "KeyValue:  " + e.KeyValue + '\n' +
         "KeyData:  " + e.KeyData;
    }

    public void KeyDemoForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        charLabel.Text = " ";
        KeyInfoLabel.Text = " ";
    }

    public void KeyDemoForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown   += KeyDemoForm_KeyDown;
        this.KeyUp     += KeyDemoForm_KeyUp;
        this.KeyPress  += KeyDemoForm_KeyPress;
    } 
}
}
```